# Using map to find the average of nested lists

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I am trying to find a concise single line of code that will calculate the mean of each nested list. There will be an input of a two dimensional list of integers and an output float value. The kicker is I am trying to do this with the map() built-in, but am unsure how. Just trying to play around with a couple of things.

Comprehension code:

```
row_sum = [(sum(idx)/float(len(idx))) for idx in matrix]
return row_sum
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into using lambda functions with the built-in `map` function?

Comment: @jtmingus why `lambda`? Why not a full function definition?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga He said he wanted to do it in one line of code

Comment: @jtmingus I suppose that's true. I just hesitate to encourage the use of `lambda` when a full function is perfectly reasonable. Also, seeking "cool one liners" shouldn't be encourage either. But I digress...

Comment: why do you need it in a *one-liner*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're intended on using `map`, this should work

```
row_sum = list(map(lambda idx: sum(idx)/float(len(idx)), matrix))
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty straight-forward. You can either make your own"mean" fucntion or use the one from the `statistics` library.:

```
>>> import statistics
>>> rows = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> list(map(statistics.mean, rows))
```

I'm on Python 3, so `/` is not integer division:

```
>>> def average(lst): return sum(lst)/len(lst)
...
>>> list(map(average, rows))
[2.0, 5.0]
```

Interesting that `statistics.mean` returned an `int`...

```
>>> rows = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,3]]
>>> list(map(statistics.mean, rows))
[2, 4.5]
```

Very interesting...

Comment: Indeed - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/statistics.py#L106

Comment: I am currently using 2.7 which I don't believe has the 'statistics' library, looks like I should install 3.

Comment: @eeskonivich yes, indeed. you should use 3 unless you have a good reason to use 2.

Answer (score 0):

Average finder Function using zip and list comprehension through user input

```
def average_finder(*args):
  n1 = int(input("Enter the first list length : "))
  for i in range(1,n1+1):
    a1 = int(input())
    a.append(a1)
  n2 = int(input("Enter the second list length : "))
  for j in range(1,n2+1):
    b1 = int(input())
    b.append(b1)
  return [sum(i)/len(i) for i in zip(*args)]
a,b = [],[]
print(average_finder(a,b))
```